# How to insert data into last affected row

Tags: php, mysql

Can i insert data into last affected row, 
first i used data.php to insert data at row '198' and 
second  used image.php to update url_path at row '198' itself but get adding as next row .

**PHP code--**

```
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

   try{
   if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
   echo "Image not recognised";
    }else{
   $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
   $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        //folder name 'images'
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="http://localhost/folder/images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

  }
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO products (pro_img_path) VALUES ('$location')"); 

  $response["success"] = 1;
  $response["message"] = "Image Added Successful!";
  die(json_encode($response));
  }
  catch(Exception $e){
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Image Not Added";
  die(json_encode($response)); 
  }

  mysqli_close($con); 
  ?>
```

Any help

Edited Code

```
    try{
    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Image not recognised";
    }else{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        //folder name 'images'
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="http://localhost/folder/images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO products (pro_img_path) VALUES ('$location')");
    $lastid=mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE products SET pro_img_path='$location' WHERE time='$lastid' LIMIT 1");

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Image Added Successful!";
    die(json_encode($response));
    }

  **Table Structure**
   -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
   -- version 4.1.6
   -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
   --
   -- Host: 127.0.0.1
   -- Generation Time: Sep 15, 2014 at 08:40 PM
   -- Server version: 5.6.16
   -- PHP Version: 5.5.9

   SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
   SET time_zone = "+00:00";


   /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
   /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
   /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
   /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

   --
   -- Database: `db` 
   --

   -- --------------------------------------------------------

   --
   -- Table structure for table `products`
   --

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
   `pid` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `category` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `subcategory` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `product_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `product_descrip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `product_price` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `more_info` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `pro_img_path` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Product Details' AUTO_INCREMENT=185 ;

   --
   -- Dumping data for table `products`
   --

   INSERT INTO `products` (`pid`, `category`, `subcategory`, `product_name`, `product_descrip`,                                                  `product_price`, `more_info`, `pro_img_path`, `time`) VALUES
   (176, 'Electronics', 'Mobile Accessories', 'Samsung Charger', 'Model G-S5830', '0890',     'MegaWat 10', '', '2014-09-15 14:19:11'),
   (182, 'Category1', 'Subcategory1', 'Electronics', 'Camera', 'Sony', 'ZeroShot', '', '2014-09-   15   17:35:42');

    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: If you want to change data in an existing row, you need to use UPDATE instead of INSERT.

Comment: yes i know, but where and how..i am new to php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update data after you insert them, then do exactly that:

after code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO products (pro_img_path) VALUES ('$location')");
```

find out insert id and assign it to variable https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

```
$lastid=mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

then run an update query similar to this one

```
UPDATE products SET column=value WHERE id='$lastid' LIMIT 1
```

Note the limit 1 clause, that is useful if you are new to php and mysql to prevent lots of errors. If you plan to update one row, then limit the query to one row in case you mess up WHERE clause.

Here is complete update syntax:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
And here is mysqli documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: tried this too, insert data only happening not updating in last updated row, how can i get the $lastid?!?

Comment: I do not understand your comment, to get last id use exactly the code i posted after some insert query `$lastid=mysqli_insert_id($con);`

Comment: if its possible i can post image to explain clearly but cant post image due to less reputation value. i will post the edited code. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: it doesnt make sense to compare time with id column like this `time='$lastid'`, you need to compare last id with your primary key column for the table. IF you have more troubles post your table structure. also why would you insert something into table and then set it to the same data?you don't need to UPDATE pro_img_path because that is what you just inserted

Comment: Added table structure, yes i just want to insert data into last affected row. (column pro_img_path)

Comment: Added table structure, yes i m trying to insert data into last affected row in column pro_img_path.

Comment: unless you understand difference between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` i can help you no more. after you have inserted pro_img_path it is already in a database and you don't need to change it again. that's like saying "hey, write down apple, then replace it with apple"

Comment: yes as u said i ran update query after insert, its working fine  when i assign the lastid manually as WHERE pid = 184 but not working as WHERE pid='$lastid' ??

Answer (score 0):

You can just use: mysqli_insert_id to get last inserted id

```
 $last_inserted_id=mysqli_insert_id($con) ;
```

and then just update with your value SET

```
UPDATE products SET column1=value1,column2=value2 WHERE id='$last_inserted_id';
```

Comment: I have tried this but still inserts the data as same not in last inserted row..